# Timer class update text of GUI?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

i created a Timer Control and set some properties

```
    private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timerClose.Enabled = true;
        timerClose.Interval = 10000;
        timerClose.Start();
    }
```

One Event of Timer

```
private void timerClose_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = timerClose.Interval.ToString();
    }
```

but do not have happened. How to update it ?

Comment: May be yourUI thread is busy in that time..Is your form hanged?

Comment: Are you sure the tick is not happening? What your doing in this tick is writing the `timerClose.Interval` value - a constant here - in your form title. It's normal then you don't see a change in your form. Did you try adding a breakpoint in the tick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your form display "10000" about 10 seconds after it opens and after that the form's caption doesn't change?

If so, your program is doing what it's supposed to be doing.  When your Timer fires it changes your form's caption to the Timer's `Interval` property, which you've set to 10000.  That value doesn't change so your form's caption won't change.

If your intention is to have your form's caption increment with every Timer tick create a class level counter that you increment on each tick, like this:

```
int _tickCounter = 0;

private void timerClose_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Text = (++_tickCounter * timerClose.Interval).ToString();
}
```

This code will change the form's caption to "10000" 10 seconds after the form opens and will increment this value by 10000 every 10 seconds after that.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure your timer is enabled and the event handler is assigned properly

Comment: SURE!. i added direct of visual studio. Please help me or code similar

Comment: Hmm.. i tested the same condition as your saying and its working here. May be give us more information or do see in InitializeComponent() method in your form regarding this timer. Or may be your main UI thread is busy.

Comment: http://ne7.upanh.com/b6.s18.d2/4f91b6ff01b2651c90deee3b5f5e5b93_36794857.untitled2.jpg
http://ne8.upanh.com/b1.s12.d1/7455e2bbf29270af3397c5c1e3223660_36794858.untitled.jpg

Comment: I added InitializeComponent(); in my form

Comment: No, it will be already added when you create a winform project. Just see in that method what all code you have written and how timer code is present. You need to do some investigation here pal. Also check if your main UI thread is busy doing some thing else?

Comment: Here: http://ne4.upanh.com/b6.s8.d1/f098353c3a9bc05c80994a07dba4c967_36795484.untitled2.jpg
http://ne6.upanh.com/b2.s18.d1/2b939262fb4b89c108a5b456d25ade68_36795486.untitled.jpg

Comment: Can you please show the InitializeComponent() method content too?
You can also try debugging by putting a break point on the timerClose.Enable line and inside the Timer_Tick event too.
Let us know if the control hits the break point.